# Unpacking a tuple's parts as function paramters

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

Imagine I have a `tuple<...>` with several types. And I want to expand the tuple's value-parts as parameters for a function with static parameters - i.e. not necessarily variadic so that the function-parameters should match the tuples parts. How can I do that ?

Comment: Are you looking for [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) (C++17)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is really (can you show some code next time?).
But you can use structured bindings to "unpack" a tuple like this :

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

void f(int x, double y)
{
    std::cout << x << ", " << y << "\n";
}

template<typename... args_t>
void g(const std::tuple<args_t...>& args)
{
    // C++17
    //const auto [x, y] = args;

    // C++11
    auto x = std::get<0>(args);
    auto y = std::get<1>(args);

    f(x, y);
}

int main()
{
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple( 1,3.14159265 );
    g(tuple);
}
```

Comment: I've tried the sample in godbolt, and it compiles only in `x86-64 gcc 11.1 / 2` `clang` and `msvc` give various compile errors. Maybe review it in godbolt and verify that code will help the OP to use it in `C++11` compilers ?

Comment: @IlianZapryanov Boy I'm sloppy today ;) fixed https://godbolt.org/z/e6qMoq85E I should have used make_tuple... keep forgetting initializer list is a newer feature.